# Why this adb logcat time won't display the year

Tags: java, date, adb, logcat

The output in all the samples i've seen is always like

```
08-16 10:34:13.280 D/MobileDataStateTracker(  886): default: This tracker is connected to sub=0
```

The date and time displaying without a year, 
the format is always MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Can I change the format to get the year as well?
For now I use a workaround like this:

```
public static Date addCurrentYearToDate(Date extractDate) {
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.setTime(extractDate);
    instance.add(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - instance.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    Date actualDate = new Date(instance.getTimeInMillis());
    return actualDate;
}
```

Comment: the title question calls for speculation. if you are just interested in better workarounds than the one you are already using - just dump the logcat in the binary form and parse it yourself

Comment: The question is not about the workaround. the question is why the implementation of the logcat /v time is without a year ?, or/and if there is a build in way within ADB to display it with year .
The workaround i'm using is OK. but its a workaround...

Comment: You can use 'adb logcat -v year' to include the year.